React Native Expo for Windows Applications
So I am working on an Expo app that is meant to be a Windows app. So far I've been testing code as a web app, and I want to build it now but there is no way for me to build it as a Windows app. The only solution I could find is to make it a bare react native app which I could do but I would prefer it to be on expo.
Any recommendations for me to build to Windows? (Soon the build needs to work for Linux and macOS too)
